# Can we use both SQL database and Firebase database while developing a web application?

Tags: sql, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database

I recently became familiar to Firebase and, after learning a lot about it, I am pretty excited about it and want to use it in the web application that my team and I are building. So I was wondering if it’s possible to use Firebase database for things like Messaging, Notifications, Authentication and other features that Firebase provides, and use SQL database for other backend stuff, like for adding the main features in the application.

And if we use these two databases (SQL and NoSQL) instead of one in our application, are there any serious disadvantages of going with this approach?

Any kind of help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use freely both databases for your application. One thing to remember is that when you are getting data from a Firebase database, you are getting it in an asynchronous way.

There is no restriction for using regarding Firebase and other databases. As long as you are using it correctly i recomand you using Firbease.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is everything alright?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mark your answer complete before as I was pretty occupied with some task. But yes your answer really helped as it cleared out my confusion. Thanks a lot :)